# iCarousel not smoothly

Tags: ios, icarousel

I'm using iCarousel to have a scroll of images. THe code is:

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform 
{
    CGFloat count = 5; 
    CGFloat spacing = 0.9f; 
    CGFloat arc = M_PI * 0.3f; 
    CGFloat radius = fmaxf(140.0 * spacing / 2.0f, 140.0 * spacing / 2.0f / tanf(arc/2.0f/count));
    CGFloat angle = offset / count * arc;
    radius = -radius;
    angle = -angle;
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, radius * sin(angle),radius * cos(angle) - radius, 0.0f);                    
    return transform;                                                    
 }
```

But when I scroll the images there is an ugly effect, the transition is not smooth and the images comes out in a jerky way, but I'd like to come out smootly. Can you help me? Thanks.

Edit: The problem is that when I scroll the images the transition is not smooth and the images comes out in front of the images on the back with a detachment from the other images. Pratically, the images comes in front of the others only when the scrolling did end and this causes a bad effect.

Answer (score 4):

We had a similar issue in our last implementation of iCarousel. Here's how we fixed it:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value {

    if (option == iCarouselOptionSpacing) {
    return value;// * 1.05f;
    } else if(option == iCarouselOptionWrap) {
    return NO;
    } else if(option == iCarouselOptionVisibleItems) {
    return 3;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Specifically, what you're probably needing is that last else if statement where we specify the number of visible items. It defaults to 1 which means that as you swipe through the new images come out in a jerky way. By specifying 3, you guarantee that the most previous item, the current item, and the next item are always loaded in memory so scrolling between them is always smooth. If this doesn't solve your problem, increase the number 3 to whatever works.

Also, don't forget to set the delegate of the iCarousel to self.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you but probably I have not explained well my problem. The problem is that when the center image comes out in front of others images, there is an ugly effect. The central image not comes out in smoothly way, but with a detachment from the other images.

Comment: Another issue may be then that the carousel view does not take up the full width of the screen. I may not be understanding your question completely though. Could you post screenshots of your issue?

Comment: I can't post a screen because the problem is evident only when I scroll the images. The central image comes out in front of others images in flat way.